# Typescript Enums - Is there any way of defining a type using an enum's values in a concise way?

Tags: typescript, types, enums

```
export enum PageNames {
  Buildings = "Buildings",
  Bedrooms = "Bedrooms",
  Lodgers = "Lodgers",
  History = "History",
}

export type PageNameT =
  | PageNames.Buildings
  | PageNames.Bedrooms
  | PageNames.Lodgers
  | PageNames.History;
```

The way that I am defining the type seems very unintuitive and unnecessarily long. Is there a more concise way to define the type, knowing that I want the type to contain all the values of the `PageNames` enum?

Comment: If you want it to have *all* the values of the enum, then you already have a type with that: `PageNames` itself. If you'd like to make an alias, you can do `type PageNameT = PageNames`, though that would just be a stylistic thing, not a necessity